# Document selection fails in view for one user

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

In Notes 9.0.1 the following formula in an Action Button on a categorised view of Company/Contacts throws the error prompt for one user, even though they have selected a Contact. The error is the same with the margin selected and the document highlighted (Caret). All other users are fine.

@If(Form!="Contact";@Do(@Prompt([Ok];"No Contact Selected";"Please select a contact profile and try again");@Return(1));"");
@Command([Compose]; "Memo").

There are no restrictions on users and access levels are the same for other users.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the cache on Notes client gets messy.

Let the user delete the database symbol from workspace and reopen the database. Usually this is already sufficient to get it to work again.

If that didn't help then delete the cache.ndk and lastly the bookmark.nsf.

Comment: Brilliant, deleting from the workspace did the trick. I would never have thought of that, thanks Knut.